# wildfly service is stopped suddenly onubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wildfly

i have installed wildfly onubuntu 14.04 LTS and have configured as a service :

```
cp /opt/wildfly/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh /etc/init.d/wildfly
```

and enable WildFly as a service:

```
sudo update-rc.d wildfly defaults
sudo update-rc.d wildfly enable
```

Add system user to run WildFly:

```
useradd --system --shell /bin/false wildfly
```

start wildfly:

```
service wildfly start
```

all is OK, but suddenly the service is stopped so i have to restart it !!
what is wrong or what i have missed ?

Comment: Logs? You should be able to get some info at /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log

Comment: @jpkrohling i have seen the log file and i have no error mentioned !! just the  wildfly service is not running suddenly .

Comment: Do you see log entries about Wildfly stopping? If so, "something" is stopping the container. If there's no indication that Wildfly is stopping, then it might have been killed by some watch dog process.

Comment: @jpkrohling ihave this log entire in the console :  *** JBossAS process (15069) received KILL signal ***

Comment: Then that's your clue. Something killed it. Check the /var/log/messages for entries at around the time the process was killed.

Comment: @jpkrohling , i don't have /var/log/messages ,can i see in other locations ?

Comment: Most likely being killed by the kernel due to low memory, trying reducing your heap size limit (-Xmx) or increasing your RAM